# How can I see the download speed in realtime on a macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, internet-speed

Is there any built-in feature to show the download/upload speed in realtime?

I cannot find it in `Network Utility -> Info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor > Network tab

Global figures at the bottom right, since boot & current [highlighted], per app figures since boot in the main section above.

The graph only updates so long as the window is open.
It doesn't differentiate between internal & external comms, so files to a network server etc will be included in these figures.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However these values update like every 5 seconds, not realtime..

Comment: View menu > Update frequency - you can get down to 1s, though tbh for network I'd have thought 5s averaging would be a better overall guide.